# Resizing an image using Intel's Integrated Performance Primitives

Tags: c, image-processing, computer-vision, image-resizing, intel-ipp

I am new to C. I am using Intel's IPP for resizing an image in VS2015. I am trying to use [ippiResizeLanczos_8u_C3R](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504353) function to resize the image.

I do not know how to see/view the resized image or get the pixel values of the resized image (image after applying the above mentioned function), as I intend to use the resized image for further processing. The function perhaps returns only the "IppStatus". But I want to get the resized image or the data information (pixel values) of the resized image as return value.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated?

Comment: According to the following example: [https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504353](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504353), The syntax is: `status = ippiResizeLanczos_8u_C3R(pSrc, srcStep, pDst, dstStep, dstOffset, dstSize, border, 0, pSpec, pBuffer);`. The resized image is returned in `pDst` (`pDst` is a pointer to a buffer of the output image).

Comment: Viewing the image:  See: [Image Watch](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e682d542-7ef3-402c-b857-bbfba714f78d), and [OpenCV Tutorial](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.co.il/2013/06/load-display-image.html). You can also save the image as BMP (for example), and watch it outside VS2015. You can also display it in a window. Personally, I prefer saving image data, using `fwrite`, and display the image using Matlab.

Comment: You can also view a raw image using [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/). Save image data to raw file: `FILE *f = NULL;fopen_s(&f, "RGB.raw", "wb");fwrite(pDst, width*height*3, 1, f);fclose(f);`. Open `RGB.raw` with IrfanView. Fill *Image width* and *Image height* parameters. Select parameters: *24 bpp (3 bytes per pixel)*, and *Interleaved (RGB RGB ...)*.

Comment: @ Rotem: Thank you for your answer. It worked for me...